# Python crashes when Tk button activates playsound() function

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run my tkinter code it crashes python when a button is pressed with the function playsound() as its command.
File here:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from playsound import playsound

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master, height=100,width=200)
        frame.pack()
        self.label1 = tk.Label(frame,
                            text="Now playing: \'A song\'",
                            fg = "blue")
        self.label1.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(frame,
                            text="Play the Beats!", fg="light green",
                            command=self.sound)
        self.button.pack()
        self.quitbutton = tk.Button(frame,
                            text="Stop the beats", fg="red",
                            command=quit)
        self.quitbutton.pack()

    def sound(self):
         playsound('/Users/willgreen1/Documents/Sounds/sound.mp3')

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()


main()
```

Comment: Please share the code of `playsound()` function otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: When you say "it crashes" do you mean that the program quits complete, or does it freeze?